# Swift Generics: Constrain Type Parameter to Protocol

Tags: swift, generics, type-parameter, generic-constraints

How do you specify that a generic type parameter can only be a protocol (or a protocol conforming to that protocol), and not a class conforming to that protocol?

For example:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    var name: String { get }
}

@objc protocol MySubProtocol: MyProtocol {
    func foo()
}

class MyImplementation: MySubProtocol {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func foo() {
        print("Foo! Name: \(self.name)")
    }
}

class InterfaceMaker<T: MyProtocol> {
    init() {}

    func makeInterface() -> NSXPCInterface {
        return NSXPCInterface(with: T.self) // Cannot convert value of type 'T.Type' to expected argument type 'Protocol'
    }


    func getProxy() -> T? {
        // Some magic in here involving `NSXPCConnection.remoteObjectProxy`
    }
}

InterfaceMaker<MySubProtocol>().makeInterface() // No error, as expected
InterfaceMaker<MyImplementation>().makeInterface() // No error, but should not work!
```

How do I specify that a generic type parameter should be a protocol?

I want to constrain `T` to only *protocols* conforming to `MyProtocol` (such as `MySubProtocol`). But the problem is, I don't know how to prevent T from being a class (such as `MyImplementation`).

I already tried constraining `T.self` (I was trying to use `where T.self : Protocol`, but that caused the error `'self' is not a member type of 'T'`).

**So how do I specify that `T` must be *a protocol conforming to `MyProtocol`, but not a class*?** If that's impossible, can I at least specify that T should be *any* protocol? It's also OK if I need to make either a [class-only protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281).

Passing `MySubProtocol` as a non-generic parameter is *not* what I am looking for as I would also like to be able to use that protocol as a type for the `InterfaceMaker.getProxy()` function. Additionally, having that function simply return `MyProtocol` (in other words, having `InterfaceMaker` be non-generic) is also not an option.

**NOTE**: To be fully clear, the reason why I need `T` to be a protocol is that I am going to pass it to `NSXPCInterface.init(with:)`, which takes a `Protocol` (which can be obtained by `SomeProtocol.self` if `SomeProtocol` is `@objc`). This means that `SomeProtocol.self.Type` is or conforms to

If this is not possible, please give a full explanation why. Also mention if it would be possible for this to be supported in a future Swift version.

**EDIT**: Another way of phrasing this is that `T.self is AnyObject.Type` should never be true. I would rather check this at compile time rather than a run time check or assertion.

Comment: Why do you care to restrict T to protocols only? Why can't I use a superclass?

Comment: @Alexander What do you mean? Why can't you use a superclass for what?

Comment: What if I'm using a class inheritance hierarchy (e.g. `Car`, `SportsCar: Car`, `FamilyCar: Car`), and not a protocol hierarchy (e.g. `CarProtocol`, `SportsCarProtocol: CarProtocol`, `FamilyCar: Protocol`). Why would you want to disallow me from using `Car` as an interface, forcing me to use `CarProtocol` instead?

Comment: @Alexander Because [`NSXPCInterface.init(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpcinterface/1410202-init) requires a `Protocol`, as I wrote in my question.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.

Comment: You could have the initialiser take a closure which maps a `T.Type` to a `Protocol`, and then always pass `{ $0 }` at the call-site (e.g https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/f90858a2bb2694fbcfc3bceb429109c4). It's pretty ugly though; and isn't 100% foolproof, as it's totally valid to do pass some other closure like `{ _ in MySubProtocol.self }`, which would ignore the type of `T.self`.

Comment: @Hamish That's basically what I was doing before. It works, but I would much rather a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `T` conforms to the protocol `AnyObject` which all classes implicitly conform, but not protocols.

So, in `InterfaceMaker`:

```
class InterfaceMaker<T: MyProtocol> {
    init() {}

    func makeInterface() -> NSXPCInterface {
        if T.self is AnyObject.Type {
           //  T is a class
        } else {
           return NSXPCInterface(with: T)
        }
    }


    func getProxy() -> T? {
        // Some magic in here involving `NSXPCConnection.remoteObjectProxy`
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood, but I am not trying to make the protocols themselves generic, rather just be able to use a protocol as a type parameter (and restrict that type parameter to protocols only).

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood what you meant. I'll rewrite the answer.

Comment: I changed the answer. I hope it's what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks, that is mostly what I'm trying to do. I had gotten that far myself. However, the problem is that *I want `T.self is AnyObject.Type` to never be possible*, probably through a generic constraint. If such a constraint is not possible, please either explain why or quote a source explaining why.

Comment: You mean at compile time?

Comment: Yes, that is the intended behavior.